# In phonegap 3.4(cordova), notification.alert or window.alert is not invoked directly. (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, alert, confirm

Platform : iOS 7.1 (iPad)

window.alert of basic embedded function and notification.alert of plugin are not invoked. (not fired).

But after I pressed home button, in reloaded app, all alerts that had not fired are invoked at the same time.

**How do I fix this bug?**

sample code is like following;

```
<input type="button" onclick="user.logout()">
```

script: (script is at between head tags)

```
var user = {
    logout : function() {
        navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure to logout?", function(button) {
        }, "confirm logout", "yes", "cancel");
    }
};
```

I tried using setTimeout function. But that's unuseful. code is like following;

```
var user = {
    logout : function() {
        navigator.notification.confirm("Are you sure to logout?", setTimeout(function(button) {
        }, 0), "confirm logout", "yes", "cancel");
    }
};
```

The reason why I used setTimeout is because it works well when I wrapped the function in setTimeout at the similar case like following;

```
pushNotification.register(setTimeout(tokenHandler,0), setTimeout(errorHandler,0), {
    "badge" : "true",
    ......
```

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have installed the following plugins via terminal:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs   
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration
```

For iOS, you'll also need these lines in the named application directory's *config.xml*:

```
<feature name="Notification">
 <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I installed notification plugin through CLI (command line interface) , so config.xml was automatically generated. Then, should I install even vibration plugin? I just used alert and confirm. function.

Comment: well it is not mandatory but I suggest you please install it.